# Pcolormesh binned PSD plotting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, physics

I am attempting to create a plot that compares binned Vertical Velocity values to binned Size values of cloud samples from a Meteorology science flight.

I have a dataframe where each datapoint has several columns representing size-bin endpoints in millimeters (mm). These bin endpoints represent particle size. The last column in the dataframe is vertical velocity recorded for each point of data. The Z values under the sizebin columns of this dataframe have units of #/cm^4 to represent number of cloud particles present in each particle size range. The Z values under the W column represent the vertical velocity in meters per second (ms-1).

I attempted to set the last column, W (vertical velocity) as the index. This means that the index for the dataframe will have repeating values, such as multiple instances of 0.3 m/s or 1.5 m/s ect...

I then transposed the dataframe to get the W values on the x-axis and sizebin values on the y-axis, and plotted the data using pcolormesh.

I was expecting something like I have drawn here in paint: [image: Number Concentration for Size vs W]

Here is the relevant part of the code I wrote:

```
CONCvWdf = pd.DataFrame()  #this is the dataframe where all CONC and W data will be concatenated.
for filename in CommonDates: #concatenate W and CONCENTRATION for all files(that represent different dates) into one giant dataframe
    df = pd.merge(MergedHDict[filename]['CONCENTRATION'], TAMMSDict[filename]['w_ms-1'], right_index=True, left_index=True) #merging w onto CONC with common indicies
    CONCvWdf = pd.concat([CONCvWdf, df], ignore_index=True) #concatenating vertically, the axis of concatenation defaults to 0 (stacks the rows)
CONCvWdf = CONCvWdf[CONCvWdf['w_ms-1'].notnull()] #removes rows where W has null values
CONCvWdf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
CONCvWdf
```

Output for this block: [image]

```
#attempting to plot data by setting w as the index
CONCvWdf.set_index('w_ms-1', inplace=True, drop=True) # replacing index that is currently displaying time with the w_ms-1 values for each corresponding time
CONCvWdf.index.name=None
CONCvWdf
```

Output for this block: [image]

```
CONCvWdf = CONCvWdf.T # transposing dataframe for plotting purposes. this sets the index to the size-bin endpoints and sets the column values to the values of W.

plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10') # figure style
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.5, 9)) # assign subplots to fig and ax
fig.tight_layout(pad = 8.5) # pad edges of figure
cmap = cmr.get_sub_cmap(cm.gnuplot2.copy(), 0, 0.9) # make copy of colormap to alter it. use cmr.get_sub_cmap to reduce the color range of the cmap
cmap.set_bad(color='white') # set 0 to white shading

#dropped last row/column of data to fit shading scheme.
CONCplot = ax.pcolormesh(CONCvWdf.columns, CONCvWdf.index.astype(float), CONCvWdf.iloc[:-1,: -1].astype(float), shading='flat', norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(), cmap = cmap, edgecolors = 'black')

cb = plt.colorbar(CONCplot, shrink=1, aspect=25, location='right', ax=ax)
cb.ax.set_title('#/cm⁴', pad=15, fontsize=10.5)

ax.set_title('Number Concentration', pad=13.5, fontsize=15, fontweight="bold")
ax.set_xlabel("W m/s", rotation=0, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("D (mm)", labelpad=12.5)
ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Output for this block: [image]

As you can see, the plot that I ended up with is wacky looking compared to what I expected. The quadrilaterals are not spaced logarithmically and there is missing data in places where I know there should be colored in quadrilaterals.

Does anyone know why?